# spf1 is rejecting some A records

Tags: dns, spf, mx-record, a-records

I setup a DNS server with a domain with mx record and some A records for subdomains.

My spf1 looks like:

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:x.x.x.x a:subdomain.somedomain.com -all"
```

what I understand is: I can send valid mails from all my A records, that ip4 and also from subdomain.somedomain.com, the rest is all rejected.

my problem is for some of the A records i get a hardfail. Let's say i have s1, s2 and s3, s3 is also mx, so I get pass for s3 and s2, but if I send a mail from s1, I get fail.

what could be the problem?

I also check some spf1 tool check like:

- http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html
- http://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester

and in those, I also get the s1 cant send valid mails.

Comment: did you change your dns records in the last hours? in this case, the receiving server (which gives you the hardfail) could be using a cached and not update version of the records related to s1

Comment: the dns server is working since more than 3 weeks (without changes) without problems.

Comment: if you put s1 in the first form of the first link you provided (kitterman.com), what do you get as output? does it pass the check?

Comment: if i put my domain, it pass; s1 is a subdomain or ip address

Comment: well, I'm sorry, but without seeing the actual domains and records you used it's hard to say where the error could be; as far as I know, it could also be a miswritten rule (e.g. domain written incorrectly).. your initial interpretation is correct

Answer (score 0):

What error messages did you get when you tried the other SPF tools?

Verify your SPF configuration using this tool: http://spf.myisp.ch. It might help you understand your rules better or show you possible configuration errors.

If you could give us your domain it would be much easier to help you. I do not recommend using a Fail (-) because of the problems related to forwarding emails.